# Averaging large csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two large csv files that are loaded as iterators using `pd.read_csv`. The files are big enough that they do not fit in memory:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', chunksize=5000000, iterator=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', chunksize=5000000, iterator=True)
```

The contents of the files look something like:

df1

```
Id   val1   val2   val3
1    0.5    0.45   0.13
2    0.11   0.18   0.20
```

df2

```
Id   val1   val2   val3
1    0.4    0.5    0.20
2    0.13   0.30   0.22
```

The `Id` column has the same values for both files. The same is true for the column names. What I want to do is take an element wise mean of the values in the `val` columns and put them in another csv with the same Id column.

So the output for this would look something like:

```
Id   val1   val2   val3
1    0.45   0.475  0.165
2    0.12   0.24   0.21
```

Any thoughts on how to go about this?
Would `read_csv` be the right approach or should I be using something like `dask` instead? What I was thinking was to iterate over the iterators concurrently and take the means of the chunks then append them to another csv file but I am not sure if that is actually possible with things like for loops

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code below, but I think you can see where I was going with it. You can use the skiprows and nrows feature. I get the feeling that dask is probably the "proper" way of doing it. I have used it a little bit in the past, their api seemed quite easy to use.

```
import pandas as pd

result = []

MAX_ROW_NO= 1000
STEP_SIZE = 10

for i in range(0,M AX_ROW_NO, STEP_SIZE):
    temp1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv",skiprows=i,nrows=STEP_SIZE)
    temp2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv",skiprows=i,nrows=STEP_SIZE)
    temp_avg = (temp1 + temp2)/2
    result.append(temp_avg)

df_avg = pd.concat(result)
```

EDIT: I think the dask solution would look a bit neater. I think it would look something like:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df1 = dd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = dd.read_csv('file.csv')

df_avg = (df1 + df2)/2

df_avg.to_csv("file_avg.csv")
```

I haven't tried this out, but the dask dataframe commands are similar to pandas ones and easy to use.